# Creating a basic vbscript to call a single command

Tags: command-line, vbscript

I have installed program where I need to run a command line in order for it to do something.  So I want to create a simple vbscript to carry out this command ion order for me to deploy the cmd to several machines using SCCM2012.

The program sits in the %ProgramFiles% directory and it is an 'exe' file with a cmd switch I am wanting to use, example

program.exe -testcmd

Hope this makes sense and can anyone assist please?

I have looked at the forums but I don't understand what all the command mean in the script.....(I am hopeless)

Comment: search SO as this has been answered multiple times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `Run` method of the `WshShell` object. Just make sure to put quotes around the path to your EXE. In VBScript, you need to escape embedded quotes (by doubling them) or you can use the `Chr(34)` statement.

```
strCmd = Chr(34) & "%ProgramFiles%\program.exe" & Chr(34) & " -testcmd"
CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run strCmd
```

Comment: Thank you Mr Bond!!!  works a treat and you have just saved me several hours of getting further frustrated.  have an amazing weekend!  :)